# Purpose of regex characters

Tags: regex

I came across a regex that has `?:` characters, for example:

```
(?:\s*)
```

So this will match 0 or more white space characters, but I can't find anywhere what is the purpose of `?:` . I know that if the case is `':?'`, `:` would be optional, but what is with `?:` ?

Comment: Did you try to read a tutorial about regex?

Comment: Searching the actual words will usually yield results `colon question mark regex`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Please provide me with the link where the sequence ?: is explained, I have a hard time finding it.

Comment: You have the wrong approach, instead of trying to decode symbols of a regex pattern one by one, read a tutorial. In this way you will no more spend your time to search.

Answer (score 0):

> (x) Matches 'x' and remembers the match, as the following example
>   shows. The parentheses are called capturing parentheses.
>
> The '(foo)' and '(bar)' in the pattern /(foo) (bar) \1 \2/ match and
>   remember the first two words in the string "foo bar foo bar". The \1
>   and \2 in the pattern match the string's last two words. Note that \1,
>   \2, \n are used in the matching part of the regex. In the replacement
>   part of a regex the syntax $1, $2, $n must be used, e.g.: 'bar
>   foo'.replace( /(...) (...)/, '$2 $1' ).
>
> (?:x) **Matches 'x' but does not remember the match. The parentheses are
>   called non-capturing parentheses, and let you define subexpressions
>   for regular expression operators to work with.** Consider the sample
>   expression /(?:foo){1,2}/. If the expression was /foo{1,2}/, the {1,2}
>   characters would apply only to the last 'o' in 'foo'. With the
>   non-capturing parentheses, the {1,2} applies to the entire word 'foo'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

It is the *match but don't capture*. In regex processing everything within `(` `)` is considered fair game to be matched and captured. The distinction is the resulting data.

For to use it, one may want to verify that a match pattern exists; *but one doesn't want all the material which makes up that match*.

Why?

Say there is a rule that a user has to add dashes to a phone number such as `303-555-1234`. By using match but don't capture we can require a match with the dashes but we can extract the capture of just saving the numbers into a database.

`(\d\d\d)(?:-)(\d\d\d)(?:-)(\d\d\d\d)`

So then we require a full match of the above, but when we extract the *captures* we only get the digits.

```
Match 0 : 303-555-1234
Match 1 : 303
Match 2 : 555
Match 3 : 1234
```

I think of it as a way to provide an **anchor** to a match to make it complete but don't need all the data.

Similar can be found when using [ExplicitCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option to only capture all within `(` `)` but leave any non parenthesis out of the match.